# Join two arrays of objects on property

Tags: javascript

In MySQL if I have two tables like this:

```
appointments

appointment_id    patient_id    appointment_time
-------------------------------------------------------
1                 42            2017-10-17 08:00:00
2                 43            2017-10-17 08:30:00
```

and

```
patients

patient_id    name
---------------------------
42            Joe Smith
43            Sally Sue
44            Jim Bob
```

then I could left join the two tables like this

```
SELECT *
FROM appointments
LEFT JOIN patients ON appointments.patient_id = patients.patient_id
```

and I would get a result like this:

```
appointment_id    patient_id    appointment_time       patient_id    name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                 42            2017-10-17 08:00:00    42            Joe Smith
2                 43            2017-10-17 08:30:00    43            Sally Sue
```

So my question is, in Javascript (ES6+), if I have two arrays of objects like this:

```
const appointments = [
  {
    appointmentId: 1,
    patientId: 42,
    appointmentTime: '2017-10-17 08:00:00'
  },
  {
    appointmentId: 2,
    patientId: 43,
    appointmentTime: '2017-10-17 08:30:00'
  }
];
```

and

```
const patients = [
  {
    patientId: 42,
    name: 'Joe Smith'
  },
  {
    patientId: 43,
    name: 'Sally Sue'
  },
  {
    patientId: 44,
    name: 'Jim Bob'
  }
];
```

How can I left join the patients array onto the appointments array based on the `patientId` property?

```
[
  {
    appointmentId: 1,
    patientId: 42,
    appointmentTime: '2017-10-17 08:00:00',
    name: 'Joe Smith'
  },
  {
    appointmentId: 2,
    patientId: 43,
    appointmentTime: '2017-10-17 08:30:00',
    name: 'Sally Sue'
  }
]
```

I know that there's the `unionBy` method in lodash, but that will remove the properties in the appointments object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do following:

```
let result = appointments.map(a => ({...patients.find(p => a.patientId === p.patientId), ...a}));
```

Comment: instead of  `name: p.name` at the end, you can just use `...p` to merge in all the props of the patient.

Comment: @BrianGlaz Of course! I've changed the answer, thanks

Comment: I'd be inclined to swap `patients` and `appointments` so the result is 1:1 mapped to appointments as asked for in the question :p

Comment: Great answer, except `patients` and `appointments` needs to be swapped as @JaromandaX stated.

Comment: @KyleMorgan not obvious from the sample input data :p

Comment: @JaromandaX True. I should have added an extra patient that didn't have any appointments.

Comment: You are right again, so I swapped them...

Comment: `patients.find(p => p.patientId === p.patientId)` should be `patients.find(p => p.patientId === a.patientId)`